# Avoid over lapping of DIV in css,jquery on conition on dragging

Tags: jquery, css, html

Hi i want to avoid overlapping of divs .here is my css ,script and html

```
///css
#body {
    background-image: url('images/marginup.jpg');
    height: 734px;
    width: 640px;
}

#body2 {
    background-image: url('images/margindown.jpg');
    height: 100px;
    width: 640px;
}
#drag1 {
    width: 636px;
    height: 107px;
    background-image: url('images/caliperupleft.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#drag2 {
    width: 636px;
    height: 107px;
    background-image: url('images/caliperdownleft.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#drag4 {
    margin-left: 430px;
    margin-top: 102px
}
#drag5 {
    margin-left: 432px;
    margin-top: -50px
}

//// my script

$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#drag3").hide();
        $(".draggable").draggable({
            containment : "parent"

        });


        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   }); 

    });


/// my html body

                       .<div id="drag1" class="draggable" >
                <img id="drag4" src="images\caliperupright.png"></img>
            </div>

            <div id="drag2" class="draggable">

                <img id="drag5" src="images\caliperdownright.png"></img>
            </div>
```

---

i want to drag the contents of the two divs in the body .But when they meet each other, the dragging should be stopped(not on mouseup but while dragging).I tried writing a function for ondrag to stop the dragging when overlapping occurs but it didn't worked .Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This site might have some answers for you.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-draggable-elements

The draggable objects has parameter control.

Good luck!